# Export Apple symbol font glyph to image

Tags: font

I am trying to add an apple symbol to an iPhone app I am writing. It there a way to export an item in the font to an image?

Comment: While developer questions are off-topic here, the question of how to export a font item to an image file is of interest to more than developers.

Comment: Must you absolutely use an image instead of the glyph itself? Can you refactor to be able to use the glyph instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that comes to mind on the Mac is to type the symbol, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, and use the resulting cross-hair pointer to draw a rectangle around the newly-typed character. That will take a screenshot of it, and save the resulting .png file to the Desktop.